# Including JS syntax with colons in a XSL template

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to create an XSL template (utilized by a Saxon processor) for embedded 360 photos using the [Photo Sphere Viewer JS library](https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/guide/). I'm running into an issue where part of the basic embed code causes a fatal error within the template:

My relevant part of my sample XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="myPanoramaTemplate">
<xsl:variable name="image" select="div/[@data-name='PanoImage']/img/@src"/>

<div id="viewer" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>
<script>
  var viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
    container: document.querySelector('#viewer'),
    panorama: '{$image}'
  });
</script>
<xsl:template>
```

This has consistently cause the following:

```
Fatal Error: QName cannot end with colon: {container:}
Fatal Error: QName cannot end with colon: {panorama:}
```

I have tried to output the script text via xsl:text, xsl:value-of, and xsl:copy-of and have had no success. I need to either find a way for the XSL to process the colons successfully or find an alternative method to utilize the JS library that avoids using colons in this context. Has anyone encountered anything similar and any solutions or workarounds?

Edit: For a simpler example without any XSL variables, I tried a test template without any variables. The same fatal errors regarding colons were flagged.

```
<xsl:template name="myPanoramaTemplate">
<script>
  var viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
    container: document.querySelector('#viewer'),
    panorama: 'path/to/panorama.jpg'
  });
</script>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show us the input data? Are you sure `<xsl:variable name="image" select="div/[@data-name='PanoImage']/img/@src"/>` is as shown? The step doing `div/[@data-name='PanoImage']` is very odd as it constructs (at least with XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1) an array containing the boolean value being the result of the comparison between the `data-name` attribute and the string `PanoImage`. Are you sure it isn't `<xsl:variable name="image" select="div[@data-name='PanoImage']/img/@src"/>` you want? Any, for any error, tell us the exact line that causes it, together with showing the exact input data.

Comment: We also need to know, if this is XSLT 3, whether `expand-text` is enabled.

Comment: This is XSL 3 with expand-text enabled. As for the variable question, I don not believe it matters. I have entered a version of the script without any variables (see below) and the same errors are being flagged regarding the colons.
`<script>
 var viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
    container: document.querySelector('#viewer'),
    panorama: 'path/to/panorama.jpg'
  });
</script>`

Comment: It matters whether you post code that throws an error "before" evaluating the code you show further down, that attempt with `/[@data-name='PanoImage']/img` should give an error "Axis step child::element(Q{}img) cannot be used here: the context item is not a node".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Martin's suggestion, escape the curly braces by doubling them.

What's happening here is that the text between the curly braces is being parsed as an XPath expression, which fails because it's not valid XPath syntax. You could write:

```
<script>
  var viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({{
    container: document.querySelector('#viewer'),
    panorama: '{$image}'
  }});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be you want/need to apply `xsl:expand-text="no"` on the literal result element `script`:

```
<script xsl:expand-text="no">
  var viewer = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
    container: document.querySelector('#viewer'),
    panorama: '<xsl:value-of select="$image"/>'
  });
</script>
```